# Can I set the uwp app store display name to be different from the installed app display name?

Tags: uwp, windows-10-universal

I would like to have a more descriptive name (for discoverability) in the Microsoft app store, but use a shorter name for the app when it is installed. I have reserved both names. I am thinking I set the App Manifest to have the short name in the Application -> Display name, and the more descriptive, store name in Packaging -> Package display name, but I don't understand the way these two names are used so I'm just guessing. Before I try this with an actual submission, I'm wondering if someone already knows if this will work.

Comment: AFAIK you can use two names if you want, but the name on the store has to be a unique one. So you're probably on the right track.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you're right. "Application -> Display name" used as a name of the app in the app list. "Visual Assets -> Short name" used as a name of the app on tiles on the start screen. "Packaging -> Package display name" used as a name in the Store. Its hint explicitly says "Specifies the app name that appears in the Store. When the package is uploaded to the Store, this name is replaced."

To make this answer a bit more useful: if you're planning to localize your app's name to different languages, you can do this by specifying path to string in .resw resources like this:

```
ms-resource:AppTitle
```

Just put it right to "Display name" field (or any other field mentioned above) and it will change title depending on the language. Although note that all localized names have to be reserved in the Store.

Comment: Great tip, @Andrey. Here's info from MS to elaborate a bit more: "All displayable strings and logos in the manifest are localizable. String references can be added in the place of a hardcoded string, by placing an **ms-resource:** scheme-specified URI into the manifest. For example, `ms-resource:String1` refers to a string called _String1_ in the Resources.resw resource file, while `ms-resource:/ManifestStrings/Shortname` refers to a string called _Shortname_ in the ManifestStrings.resw resource file."