# How to change Xamarin UWP App Name

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.uwp

I have a Xamarin.Forms application that builds to Android, iOS, and UWP. On iOS the App Name shows up as just "AppName" under the icon. On UWP, however, the app name is "AppName.UWP".

**How do I remove the .UWP in my app name?**

I have tried editing the Assembly name, the namespace, etc, and none of it seems to be working.

Comment: Do you see a "Package.appxmanifest" file in your UWP project?

Comment: @j.f. Of course I do... now. Haha. Was totally overlooking it earlier. Yes, I opened it up and of course changed the Display name. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There should be a "Package.appxmanifest" file in your UWP project. Open that up and you should see "Display name", "Short name", and "Package display name" among other settings. Hovering over the setting text will tell you what they each do. [This Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37694700/3711928) has some more information.

**Application > Display name:** Specifies the full name of the app.

**Visual Assets > Short name:** Specifies an abbreviated name for the app.

**Packaging > Package display name:** Specifies the app name that appears in the Store. When the package is uploaded to the Store, this name is replaced.

You can find all of the details on Microsoft's [App package manifest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/schemas/appxpackage/appx-package-manifest) page.